# How to correctly compute the gradient of a curve using numpy gradient?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a curve which is composed of 1200 values and i just want to compute its derivative so i use numpy gradient function.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('test_data.csv', delimiter=',')
support = np.array(np.arange(1200))
plt.plot(support, data)
plt.show()
plt.plot(support, np.gradient(data, support))
plt.show()
```

Here is the curve plot:

[image: Curve plot]

And here is the gradient plot:

[image: Gradient plot]

Why is there positives values at the begining of the gradient curve ? My curve is strictly decreasing on [0; 600], and why is there so much noise ?

I'm putting down the data in the CSV if you want to check it out:

https://pastebin.com/hC7GVeih

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you zoom in at the beginning of the curve, you can see that it's not strictly decreasing.

[image: Zoomed plot]

Your data is noisy, and the gradient of a noisy function always appears noisier.

You can apply a simple moving average to smooth your data:

```
w = 25
smooth = np.convolve(data, np.ones(w), 'valid') / w
smooth_support = support[w//2:-w//2+1]
plt.plot(smooth_support, smooth)
plt.show()
plt.plot(smooth_support, np.gradient(smooth, smooth_support))
plt.show()
```

[image: Smoothed]
[image: Smoothed gradient]

Of course, instead of using a flat convolution kernel (like `np.ones()`) you can use a better approach from [scipy.signal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#module-scipy.signal).

Comment: Thanks a lot, should have zoomed in, i'll try smoothing my curves :)